# Three-Dimensional Picture from 2D tiles

Tags: optics, particle-detectors

The CMS Silicon Pixel detector can create three-dimensional pictures of a particle's trajectory. It specifically says that "because the detector is made of 2D tiles, rather than strips, and has a number of layers, we can create a three-dimensional picture."

Why the emphasis on "rather than strips"?

Link:
http://cms.cern/detector/identifying-tracks/silicon-pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a trajectory in space you need an (x,y,z) . The two dimensional panels provide the (x,y) of their location ( with error their width) and the layers the z variable from their z location . A strip has only one dimension in the panel plane, so cannot give two coordinates. From the description of [strip detectors](https://www.nuclear-power.net/nuclear-engineering/radiation-detection/semiconductor-detectors/silicon-based-semiconductor-detectors/silicon-strip-detectors/) a complicated geometry layer  would be needed to get an extra variable, introducing unnecessary errors.